# Best way to know if a user has logged off

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, browser

I was wondering what would be the best way to detect browser log off, I already have a timer set that invalidates the session after 30 minutes. But what if the user didn't not log off but simply exited the browser? Another user opens up the same browser on the same computer, before 30 minutes, because the setting of going back to where you left off is toggled on in your browser settings.

So far, we have a timer set every 30 minutes, we have a log out button, but other than that what could be the best way to log off or to know if a user exited its browser. The reason I am asking for this is because there is a lot of security issues related to the setting in chrome, firefox, etc. that lets users go back where they left off. Especially when browser crashes or forced to quit, if you open it the next day, it will go back to where you left off if you click "Restore" button when browser prompts you because it quit unexpectedly.

What about session hijacking?

Currently using Java / JSP with Javascript / jQuery on WebSphere.

Comment: Have you looked into session cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it would be using [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).
A websocket always maintains a constant connection between user's browser and the server and raises an event on connection close.

You can do it using Node.js's [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) library. If a user closes the browser, the TCP connection will break and an event would be raised on which you can terminate the session.

A similar thing can be done using [ASP.net's SignalR.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting)

Comment: I was looking more of a Java way or JavaScript way of doing it without implementing a new language into the application. Let me know if there might be an alternative way.

How About HTML 5 WebSockets and JWebSockets (Java)

Comment: Node.js uses JavaScript only.
You cannot do it with client side JavaScript. You need something to listen on server also which can terminate the session when connection breaks.
JavaScript alone cannot work in this case.
Server Side JavaScript(Node.js) is a must. :)

Comment: Node.js needs implementation / installation though, I was thinking something more simple. I don't know if our servers would support node.js

Comment: They will for sure. Node is available for windows, linux, solaris and mac.

Comment: Any alternatives to mainframe? Since Websphere on mainframe doesn't support node.js

Answer (score 0):

you could add a ping page, basically with javascript you'll invoke this page every 30 seconds, you can implement this with memcached. if it's missing 2/3 pings the user is really offline.

Comment: What if there's 30,000 users online... that method will be heavy for the server to process. Huge performance decline

Comment: not really, considering that you can share the load across memcached servers and you really don't need any access to any db to do this. I used this with a site that ad 17k concurrent users on a single memcached node, the load was nil